# How to load null data with file?

Tags: mysql, null

Create sample database and table to use with.

```
create database `test`;
use `test`;
create table `test` (`value` float(10,2) null);
insert into test (value) values (null);
select value  from test;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  NULL |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i want to create a  txt file ,when you load it ,null data can be loaded into the test table.

```
delete from test;
```

Here is my data file named `test.txt` showed in vim(:set list).
[image]

Load the file into table.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "test.txt"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' \w;
select value from test;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  0.00 |
|  0.00 |
|  0.00 |
|  0.00 |
|  0.00 |
+-------+
```

How to load `null` data for `value` field with file in my case?
How to create this kind of data file,the value field is `null` after you load it?

The runtime environment:win10+mysql-5.7.

```
select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.22    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Show test.txt file in vim with `set list`.

```
\N$
\N^I$
```

case:without set

Load it without `(value) SET value = (CASE WHEN @value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @value END)`.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "f:/test.txt"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' \W;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1
Warning (Code 1262): Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

select * from  test;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  0.00 |
|  NULL |
+-------+
```

case:with set
Load it with `(value) SET value = (CASE WHEN @value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @value END)`.

```
delete from test;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "f:/test.txt"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(value)SET value = (CASE WHEN @value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @value END) \W;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1
Warning (Code 1262): Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

 select * from test;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  NULL |
|  NULL |
+-------+
```

Thank @Schwern.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "f:/test.txt"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  \W;
```

Either works fine with no warnings.

Comment: You can use `SET` within `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to set the value of the column it might work.  see docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html ... Maybe something like this  `(value) SET value  = (CASE WHEN @value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @value END)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\N`.

The problem is all your input lines have an extra empty field. Tab terminates the field, like a comma. You've used it as if it encloses it like quotes. For example, your first line `^Inull^I` is three fields. The first is empty. The second contains `null`. And the third is empty.

MySQL should have said something like

```
Query OK, 5 rows affected, 8 warnings (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 8
```

You can read those warnings with `show warnings`.

```
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                   |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1                                |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 2                                |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 3                                |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 4                                |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 4 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 5                                |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

All you need is this:

```
\N$
```

---

Note that `lines terminated by` is sensitive to Unix vs Windows newlines. From the docs...

> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator.

This explains the warnings you are getting.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Either works fine with no warnings. I'm guessing the final field terminator is optional because the line terminates. This would make it more compatible with CSV formats where a field *separator* is used rather than a field *terminator*.

Comment: In every case,there is a warning info,@Schwern i don't know why would you say Either works fine with no warnings.?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature As I suspected, you have Windows newlines in your file. You need to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.

Comment: Thank  Schwern , `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.